# Can we do a If in Axios - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, axios

I'm writing this post because i would like to know if it's possible to do a `if` in axios.
Basically i'm trying to send only variables with contents with axios.

I have a code globally like this :

```
 async handleSubmit(event) {
  this.setState({ loading: true });

  setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({ loading: false });
  }, 2000);

 event.preventDefault();
 const {
   name_contact='', name_contact1='', endfr='', endfr_1='',
 } = this.state;


 const name = [name_contact, name_contact1].filter(v =>v).join(',');
 const end = [name_contact, name_contact1].filter(v =>v).join(',');

 await axios.post(
  ' MY_endpoint API',
  {
    name, end
  })
}
```

For example if `name_contact` and `name_contact1` are empty, i'm going to receive `name=""`
with my axios.post.
But i'm trying to delete name or end if they're empty for axios.post to send only what is useful and not a completely empty variable.

So I tell myself that I could do an `if` in axios to check the content of a variable and send it if there is content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generic way to not explicitly check each field

```
const payload = {name, end, /*other fields*/};

//filtering not empty fields
const result = Object
.keys(payload)
.filter(key => payload[key] !== '')
.reduce((result, key) => ({...result, [key]: payload[key]}), {});

// Or just use Lodash _.pickBy
const result = _.pickBy(payload, field => field !== '');

await axios.post('MY_endpoint API', result);
```

Comment: With using the first method, i'm just getting "name=undefined" and "end=undefined" if i'm sending nothing with the axios. And with pickBy, i'm literally getting nothing. (i have a lambda to get the datas, but if i'm looking in the logs, i'm receiving nothing)

Comment: No you won't get `undefined`. If all fields are empty strings, you got empty object. Check `Object.keys(result).length` and don't send that request at all. `if(Object.keys(result).length) axios.post(...)`

Comment: okay no sorry, it's working. Thanks a lot, i was just no printing the good thinks in my lambda.

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to axios. Just add items to data object conditionally:

```js
await axios.post(
  ' MY_endpoint API',
  {
    ...(name && { name }),
    ...(end && { end })
  })
}
```

Also lodash can help you here:

```js
await axios.post(
  ' MY_endpoint API',
  _.pickBy({
    name, end
  }, Boolean))
}
```

Comment: With this method, I end up with name=undefined, it's not really my objective. But thanks you

Comment: and i'm not receiving nothing with pickBy. Literally nothing

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
var dataToSend={};

if(name!="" &&end!=""){
dataToSend={name,end}
}

// Send a POST request
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user',
  data: dataToSend
});
```

Comment: globally i'm going to have the same problem. I'm going to have a "dataToSend" with nothing